# How to hide next state and previous state in vuex logs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Here is how I initialize vuex:

```
Vue.use(Vuex);
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  plugins: [createLogger({logger: console, collapsed: true})],
  strict: true,
  state: state,
  getters: getters,
  mutations: mutations,
  actions: actions,
});
Vue.prototype.$store = store;
export default store;
```

The logs I get are like:

> 'mutation ADD_VIDEO_CREDIT @ 15:53:13.903'
>
> '%c prev state' 'color: #9E9E9E; font-weight: bold' { profile: // a huge pile of text
>
> '%c mutation' 'color: #03A9F4; font-weight: bold' { type: 'ADD_CREDIT', payload: {credit: 4} }
>
> '%c next state' 'color: #4CAF50; font-weight: bold' { profile: // another huge pile of text

In my dreams I would like to only get:

> type: 'ADD_CREDIT', payload: {credit: 4}

What is the closesd I cat get to that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The createLogger function takes few functions, you can use the filter function to override the actual mutation results to print in console in the required format

```
Vue.use(Vuex);
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  plugins: [
   createLogger({
  logger: console,
  collapsed: true,
  filter (mutation, stateBefore, stateAfter) {
    console.log(mutation);
    return false;
  },
}),
],
  strict: true,
  state: state,
  getters: getters,
  mutations: mutations,
  actions: actions,
});
Vue.prototype.$store = store;
export default store;
```

Comment: Yes I have seen that, can you please tell me how can I initialize my logger so that it would behave as I want?

Comment: I can't find a way to fix my problem with this.

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce the same in my local

Comment: Hey @yukashimahuksay, update the answer, its is working as expected, please let me know if it resolves your issue. Thanks in Advance